# Several select count(*) in a single query

Tags: mysql

[image]

I have a mysql table(tbl_subscriptiondetails) like the above.Here the last column i.e
'test_status' could have possible values C,S & Y only.
Using a single query i would like to fetch data in the manner
as shown below

[image]

But the query that i'm using gives me undesired results.My query is

```
    SELECT pkg_name, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_subscriptiondetails WHERE test_status='C' AND mem_id=3) AS completed, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_subscriptiondetails WHERE test_status='S' AND mem_id=3) AS started, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_subscriptiondetails WHERE test_status='Y' AND mem_id=3) AS remaining 
FROM tbl_subscriptiondetails 
WHERE mem_id=3 
GROUP BY pkg_name
```

and the result is
[image]

[image]

Please advise what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have independent queries. Try to add dependency: `AND t1.pkg_name = t.pkg_name`

Comment: Your logic of remaining is supposed to be 'S' + 'Y'?

Comment: Also you can write it without subqueries: `SELECT SUM(IF(test_status='C', 1, 0))`

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a51a/7) with `IF`'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a subquery for each count, instead of counting as part of the main query. Therefore, your filter conditions aren't behaving as you expect them to. You can change it like so, to do the conditional count:

```
SELECT pkg_name, 
SUM( case when test_status='C' then 1 else 0 end) AS completed, 
SUM( case when test_status='S' then 1 else 0 end) AS started, 
SUM( case when test_status='Y' then 1 else 0 end) AS remaining 
FROM  tbl
WHERE mem_id = 3
GROUP BY pkg_name
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0a42a/1)

Comment: better to exclude mem_id to where